# Use Node.js only for chat and not to serve the index page

Tags: php, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have asked two questions but I still couldn't solve the problem. I am trying to create a chat application with Node.js and Socket.io. The problem is that every example I have seen in the internet uses Node.js to serve the webpage also and I don't want to do that; I want PHP to serve me the page and I want Node.js to help me with the chat. So I haven't got much far.

The code for my index.php is given below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Chat app.</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node:1337/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost/node:1337');
            socket.on('news', function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my code for the app.js where I have written my Node.js code.

```
var app = require('http').createServer()
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(app);

app.listen(1337);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

As you can see, I want node to communicate with each other through port 1337, as port 80 is already taken by xampp. But whenever I try to access the index page with the browser, the console shows me "access is forbidden". Incidentally, if it is necessary, my index.php, app.js, node_modules folder all are in htdocs/node folder. I am using a Windows 8 OS. I have asked this question before but the answer wasn't much helpful. They said something about [reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10440965/using-socket-io-with-nodejs-on-a-server-with-apache-as-a-reverse-proxy). I don't know what that means, let alone how to do that.

Comment: why exactly are the `.js`, `node_modules` inside apaches' `htdocs` ? only the `socket.io-client.js` is required at client-side and you don't seem to include it correctly..

Comment: @GeoPhoenix, thanks for replying, i didn't get you. how should i include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the client socket.io.js inclusion. Iam not sure though
Try including your socket.io.js as server:port/socket.io/socket.io.js or see this link [cannot get client server running using express in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15561708/cannot-get-client-server-running-using-express-in-node-js/15566578#15566578)
Thanks.