# Allowing recipients to see updates automatically

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I realised when testing my website, that a user that receives a message/comment has to refresh the page before they see any alerts or changes.

In `comments.php?do=comment&id=1` shows the post with the `id` of 1 for users to comment on.

I use this form to submit a comment, and this is shown by a mysql fetch on the same page to show the content.

`<form action="" method="post" >
input name="getcomment" type="text" value="What are your thoughts?"/>
<input value="Comment!" type="submit"/>
</form>`

I have seen quite a few resources online on updating the content automatically when a new comment has been submitted *(for the recipient)* but I am not sure which is best. Bearing in mind this is a very **small** scale website.

1. What could be my options? (JQuery/Ajax seems the simplest) But is 'polling' the database inefficient?
2. How would I implement this (which I am finding most difficult)

Comment: Take a look at [socket.io](http://socket.io), a framework you can use together with php to notify clients of events like this. For the second question I can link to another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6420431/208753)

Comment: Thanks, I will look into that. What makes socket.io advantageous over other similar services? (if any).

Comment: Well I personally use signalr, but that's for .NET. Basically signalr does what socket.io does, but socket.io is more mature. It's definitely more easy that it looks.

Comment: Oh okay, yeah it does look slightly confusing but I will definitely read up on this

Answer (score 1):

You just need to poll your php script every few second's like this.
and *Bearing in mind this is a very small scale website* polling can do what you want.

```
setInterval(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: "getComments.php"
   }).done(function(comment) {
     // show new comments
     $('#comment_section').append(comment);
   });
},5000); // poll every 5 seconds
```

Comment: Thanks! In the `'show new comments'` section, what would I put into there? The <div> to refresh that holds my `SELECT` query?

Comment: what do you mean by this _The <div> to refresh that holds my SELECT query_

Comment: So in my `comments.php`, I have the post that is being commented on. And below this is a `<div>` containing a `SELECT` query to relay the comments. It is this that needs to be updated automatically.

Comment: No.. move that query part to another php `getComments.php` and simply poll that php with ajax.

Comment: Just the query? Because I also use a `mysqli_fetch_array` following the query in `comments.php`

Comment: I mean , the part that get's and display's the comments from database...... essentially.. all the code associated to comments should be moved to new php.]

Comment: And so essentially, in `comments.php` will have an empty `<div>` called `#comment_section`?

Comment: I got this working (kind of) however, it non-stop is posting over and over again the same content of the whole <div>! Not only recent comments but all from the database

Comment: you need to manage a variable that holds the time when you last retrieved the comments form DB and every time you need to get comments just use `WHERE time > lastRetrievedTime` in your query, and update the variable every time you retrieve comments....

Answer (score 0):

I think that your best options would be to use JQuery/Ajax as it is much cheaper alternative to using sockets.

IF it is not important for your users to receive immediate updates, you can just poll.

Comment: What do you mean by 'cheaper alternative'?

Comment: That's not true, bandwidth wise and performance wise sockets are far superior.

Comment: That is what I had assumed surely polling the database would be more inefficient than using a socket